# Codeigniter - I can't use numbers at end of urls

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following in my main controller

```
public function chapter-1 () {
    $data['title'] = "Hello";
    $this->load->view("site_head", $data);
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_content");
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}
```

but when I write "public function chapter-1", the number 1 lights up in orange, and I was hoping I can use the chapter-1 to get www.webpage.com/chapter-1 onto my site.  How can I get it done?

Comment: function name cannot contains hyphen( `-`) use underscore.like this `chapter_1`

Comment: Just change the function name to chapter1 and it should work..

Answer (score 5):

I would highly advise against your current plan.

Below is a much more maintainable and DRY solution:

```
class Chapter extends CI_Controller
{
    public function view($chapter_num = 1) {

        // Create a model to help you pull data from the database
        $this->load->model('chapter_helper');

        $data = $this->chapter_helper->get_chapter($chapter_num)

        $this->load->view("site_head", $data);
        $this->load->view("site_header");
        $this->load->view("site_content");
        $this->load->view("site_footer");
    }
}
```

So now you could access it like this:

> www.example.com/chapter/view/1
>
> www.example.com/chapter/view/2
>
> www.example.com/chapter/view/3

And best of all, you will not need to create multiple functions inside of your controller.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with MonkeyZeus' solution although I don't know where is controller name in his code. However, here is idea how you can use dashes in url. In `APPPATH . 'config/routes.php'` file, at the bottom of the it add:

```
$route['controller-name/chapter-(:num)'] = 'controller_name/chapter_$1';
```

Read in [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=route) how to not overwrite latest lines in this file.

Comment: Hey, I just read your answer and I had a complete brain-fart. I've updated my answer so that it makes sense.

Comment: Hah. No problem. I was scared it is something with chapter_helper, like what kind of helper is that? :)